# Performing checksum calculation on python bytes type

Tags: byte, python-3.8

First time I need to work on raw data (with different endianness, 2's complement, ...) and thus finally figured out how to work with the bytes type.
I need to implement the following checksum algorithm. I understand the C code, but wonder how to gracefully do this in Python3...
I'm sure I could come up with something that works, but would be terribly inefficient or unreliable

> The checksum algorithm used is the 8-bit Fletcher algorithm. This algorithm works as follows:
>
> - Buffer[N] is an array of bytes that contains the data over which the checksum is to be calculated.
> - The two CK_A and CK_A values are 8-bit unsigned integers, only! If implementing with larger- sized integer values, make sure to mask both
>   CK_A and CK_B with the value 0xff after both operations in the loop.
> - After the loop, the two U1 values contain the checksum, transmitted after the message payload, which  concludes the frame.
>
> ````
> CK_A = 0, CK_B = 0 For (I = 0; I < N; I++)
>     {
>     CK_A = CK_A + Buffer[I]
>     CK_B = CK_B + CK_A
>     } ```
> ````

My data structure is as follows:

```
source = b'\xb5b\x01<@\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00hUX\x17\xdd\xff\xff\xff^\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xa6\x00\x00\x00F\xee\x88\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa5\xf5\xd1\x05d\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00j\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\xcb\x86\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x007\x01\x00\x00\xcd\xa2'
```

I came up with a couple of ideas on how to do this but have issues.
The following is where I am now, I've added comments on how I think it would work (but doesn't).

```
for b in source[5:-2]:

    # The following results in "TypeError("can't concat int to bytes")"
    # So I take one element of a byte, then I would expect to get a single byte.
    # However, I get an int.
    # Should I convert the left part of the operation to an int first?
    # I suppose I could get this done in a couple of steps but it seems this can't be the "correct" way...

    CK_A[-1:] += b

    # I hoped the following would work as a bitmask, 
    # (by keeping only the last byte) thus "emulating" an uint8_t
    # Might not be the correct/best assumption...

    CK_A = CK_A[-1:] 
    CK_B[-1:] += CK_A
    CK_B = CK_B[-1:]
ret = CK_A + CK_B
```

Clearly, I do not completely grasp how this Bytes type works/should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I was making things too difficult...

```
    CK_A = 0
    CK_B = 0

    for b in source:
        CK_A += b
        CK_B += CK_A

    CK_A %= 0x100
    CK_B %= 0x100
        
    ret = bytes()
    ret = int.to_bytes(CK_A,1, 'big') + int.to_bytes(CK_B,1,'big')
```

The %=0x100 works as a bit mask, leaving only the 8 LSB...